# How to pass item value from one page to another without a Button?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, items, oracle-apex-18.2

In ORACLE APEX, I need to pass an item value from one page to another that is not directly related to so I cannot use neither a link column nor a button that redirect to that page. Is there other way to do it?

Comment: If you do not need to manipulate the value of the item on the landing page, then you do not need to pass the value, just access the item from the page directly. You have access to items from one page to another. Of course, the value of this item must be in session.

Answer (score 3):

"Another page" (for example, page 2) can reference item value from "one page" (for example, page 1), such as

```
:P2_ITEM := :P1_ITEM;
```

See page 2 item's

- source
- default value
- on load dynamic action

Page 1 item's value has to be in session state (which doesn't mean that you can see it on the screen), otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

When or in what event will that value have to pass? For example, when you change the value of an item, when you load the page, etc.